# Why does setting a new value to a variable not reflect in console?

Tags: javascript, console

Was going through MDN's tutorials and wanted expand on a part which is where I ran into this issue. When I ran the code below:

```
    let examScore = 45;
    let examHighestScore = 70;
    examReport = `You scored ${ examScore }/${ examHighestScore } (${ Math.round((examScore/examHighestScore*100)) }%). ${ examScore >= 49 ? 'Well done, you passed!' : 'Bad luck, you didn\'t pass this time.' }`;
```

it returns `"You scored 45/70 (64%). Bad luck, you didn't pass this time."` When I set a new value to `examScore`, the return doesn't reflect the new value.
I set a new value for `examScore` then ran `examReport` again like below.

```
    examScore = 60;
    examReport;
```

I was expecting:

```
"You scored 60/70 (86%). Well done, you passed!"
```

What I got was:

```
"You scored 45/70 (64%). Bad luck, you didn't pass this time."
```

I even checked `examScore` and it returns `60`.
Not sure if its a developer console or js issue. Any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: You are not reassigning `examReport`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`examReport` has been already evaluated in previous line.

You need to set it again as new template string and it will work.

Comment: @CheckeredBurrito, I don't know if in closed question this can be done, but if possible, please accept my answer (the green tick). Thank you :)